# Rotating image in File for Android

Tags: android, image, file, bitmap, rotation

I'm having problems with trying to rotate an image before cropping it. I have tried calling `setRotation` on the Image View I want to rotate and it rotates the imageView successfully. I realized this wasn't a solution because when I call CropImageIntentBuilder it passes in the original Image View without any rotation.

In the code below I have tried a different approach by saving the image to a File and passing that file to CropImageIntentBuilder but I am still having the same problem. Please let me know if there is any advice you can offer on this or if I'm approaching this the wrong way. Also if I need to post more of the code from the app please let me know.

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap (Bitmap source, float angle){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return  Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),matrix,true);
}


private void executeCropImageIntent() {
    //This is the cropIntent that is called using nexuss 10
    try{
         bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mSingleton.mCropFileTemp.toURI().toString()));
        //mSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90));
        rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90);
        try{

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(mSingleton.mCropFileTemp);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();}
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(null, "Save file error!");
    //      Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.messageMissingGPS), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        }

    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("JudgeMainFragment", "cannot take picture", e);
    }

            CropImageIntentBuilder intentBuilder = new CropImageIntentBuilder(0, 0, 0, 0, Uri.parse(mSingleton.mCropFileTemp.toURI().toString()));
            //  intentBuilder.setSourceImage(Uri.parse(mData.getImage()));
            intentBuilder.setSourceImage(Uri.parse(mSingleton.mCropFileTemp.toURI().toString()));
            startActivityForResult(intentBuilder.getIntent(this), IJudgeSingleton.REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling  `rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90);`. but not assigning the returned `BitMap` to any variable. and then you are using the old bitmap which is not rotated. so change this line

```
rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90);
```

into this

```
bitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90);
```

Comment: You my friend are awesome for this answer thanks so much it worked like a charm. I've been struggling with this for days so finally I decided to get on here and got an answer in less than a day. I would upvote this answer but my reputation isn't high enough to do that yet. Thanks again this really REALLY helped.

Comment: Yea probably but how do I do that?